# VB Sending double click to another form X and Y

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent

What i want to do is have a application running in background which capture key pressed on keyboard then send a double click to a X and Y coord in the windows im on (not the vb program).

This is what i have so far:

```
Public Class Form1

Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Integer
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As IntPtr)

Private Sub PerformMouseClick(ByVal LClick_RClick_DClick As String, ByVal xCoord As Integer, ByVal yCoord As Integer)
    Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As Integer = 2
    Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As Integer = 4
    Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Integer = 6
    Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Integer = 8
    If LClick_RClick_DClick = "RClick" Then
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, xCoord, yCoord, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, xCoord, yCoord, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
    ElseIf LClick_RClick_DClick = "LClick" Then
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xCoord, yCoord, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xCoord, yCoord, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
    ElseIf LClick_RClick_DClick = "DClick" Then
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xCoord, yCoord, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xCoord, yCoord, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xCoord, yCoord, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xCoord, yCoord, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.W) Then
        PerformMouseClick("LClick", 74, 1103)
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

But the double doesnt happen. The key (W) is recognized outside my vb everything is fine for that. I just dont know how to send a double click at coordinate. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: So the left-click *does* work? How about adding a timeout between the mouse events, maybe `Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)`?

Comment: no the left click doesnt work too i was trying if dclick or lclick was working with the Start button of windows but nothing was hapenning

Comment: And im not getting any error message so i dont know whats going on. The performmouseclick is a code i got from googling.

Comment: You are missing MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, &H8000.  It says that the x and y coordinates are absolute.  Add it to the value of the 1st argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you:

```
Public Structure PointAPI
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer
End Structure
Module Module_SetMouseclick
    Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
    Public Declare Auto Function SetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer) As Long
    Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" (ByRef lpPoint As PointAPI) As Boolean
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
    Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As Integer = &H4
    Public x, y As Integer
    Public Sub Position_Click(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal click As Boolean)
        SetCursorPos(x, y)
        If click Then
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 1)
        Else
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 1)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

and access it with

```
Module_SetMouseclick.Position_Click(500, 500, True)
Module_SetMouseclick.Position_Click(500, 500, False)
```

This works pretty well for me. IT also saves the current position if you want to reset it.